# using numpy broadcast_to create a repeated view of every element in array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to repeat every element in an array n times without creating a new location on the memory to reproduce the same output as np.repeat shown below.

using `np.broadcast_to` i managed to only repeat the whole array n times not every element inside it.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
arr
```

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

```
np.repeat(arr, 6, axis=0)
```

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [57]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])                                                               
In [58]: rarr = np.repeat(arr, 3, axis=0)                                                            
In [59]: rarr                                                                                        
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

You can't use `broadcasting` to duplicate this.  The underlying raveled memory is different:

```
In [60]: arr.ravel()                                                                                 
Out[60]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
In [61]: rarr.ravel()                                                                                
Out[61]: array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4])
```

With `broadcast_to` the regular broadcasting rules apply - new leading dimensions are automatic, and size 1 dimensions are scaled.  Thus

```
In [64]: np.broadcast_to(arr, (3,2,2))                                                               
Out[64]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

All values have been 'replicated', but the shape and order is different from your repeat.  Any attempt to transpose and reshape elements will result in a copy (with no memory savings).

A different broadcasting produces a layout closer to the `repeat`:

```
In [70]: np.broadcast_to(arr[:,None,:], (2,3,2))                                                     
Out[70]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[3, 4],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]]])
In [71]: np.broadcast_to(arr[:,None,:], (2,3,2)).reshape(6,2)                                        
Out[71]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

[70] is a view (readonly), but [71] is a copy, with the same memory footprint as `rarr`.